# Import org.openntf cannot be resolved

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

I have a Notes V11.0.1 designer client and configured a widget that imports the latest OpenNTF Domino API (downloaded from OpenNTF website) through an update site.

The plug-in is loaded in the designer
[image]

I created a new application and added the library to XSP Properties.
[image: Xpages Properties]

But when I create a simple Java class and want to import org.openntf.domino.*, I get an error:

```
package test;
import org.openntf.domino.*;
public class Test {
    public static void test() {
       Session session = null;
    }
}
```

Error: the import org.openntf cannot be resolved.
Building the app does not solve the problem.

In the MANIFESST.MF I get the following error
[image]

Any idea why this goes wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's most likely that the default Target Platform in 9.0.1FP10 and newer (11.0.1 included) is broken: https://frostillic.us/blog/posts/2018/10/19/058650e080e352178525832b00519d2c